# How to configure charset/encoding for file upload in a Java web application independently of application server?

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, character-encoding

My whole webapp uses UTF-8 (html pages are properly encoded, http-equiv is properly set, JVM default is also set). All requests and responses work fine, except the filename when uploading a file.

The form hast `multipart/form-data` and `acceptcharset="UTF-8"`. But the servlet receives invalid characters when the filename contains special characters, like the german `ü`.

On Tomcat I can solve the problem by setting `URIEncoding` in the `Connector` configuration. But what if I want to provide a `.war` webapp which works on any webapp server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed `acceptcharset="UTF-8"` to `accept-charset="UTF-8"` in my HTML form. Now it works without changing the `Connector` configuration.